# How scrape from table that changes class from "odd" to "even"

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape text and value from a table that has a dozen of rows named "odd" and "even", one after another.

Webpage: https://transparenciamunicipios.tce.ce.gov.br/index.php/municipios/receitas/mun/002/versao/2021

Code sample:

```
    <tr class="odd">

        <td class="">Transferencias de Recursos do FUNDEB - Principal</td>

        <td align="right" class="">6.324.609,86</td>

      </tr>

 

    <tr class="even">

            <td class="">Cota-Parte do ICMS - Principal</td>

            <td align="right" class="">3.765.015,28</td>

          </tr>

 

    <tr class="odd">

            <td class="">Transferencias de Complementacao da Uniao ao FUNDEB - Princ.</td>

            <td align="right" class="">3.359.964,56</td>

          </tr>
```

Comment: what do you use for scarping? Where is your code. Some tools can use regex like `odd|even` which means `odd or even` and `xpath` can use `or`

Comment: add `css selector` can use `,` (comma) like `or` -  something like `.odd, .even`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I added example with `rvest` in `R`

---

I don't use `R` and I don't know what tools you use but...

- `xpath` can use `or`

  ```
  '//tr[@class="odd" or @class="even"]'
  ```
- `css selector` can use `,` (comma) as `or`

  ```
  '.odd, .even'
  ```

  or

  ```
  'tr.odd, tr.even'
  ```

---

I have example only in Python.

I don't read from url because I can't access it - it shows timeout.

I added `<tr class="advertisement">`

```py
text = '''
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="">Transferencias de Recursos do FUNDEB - Principal</td>
    <td align="right" class="">6.324.609,86</td>
</tr>

<tr class="even">
    <td class="">Cota-Parte do ICMS - Principal</td>
    <td align="right" class="">3.765.015,28</td>
</tr>

<tr class="advertisement">
    <td class="">Buy new cat</td>
    <td align="right" class="">3.359.964,56</td>
</tr>

<tr class="odd">
    <td class="">Transferencias de Complementacao da Uniao ao FUNDEB - Princ.</td>
    <td align="right" class="">3.359.964,56</td>
</tr>
'''

import lxml.html

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(text)

print('\n--- xpath ---\n')

rows = soup.xpath('//tr[@class="odd" or @class="even"]')

for row in rows:
    print(row.attrib['class'], row.text_content())

print('\n--- css ---\n')
    
rows = soup.cssselect('.odd, .even')

for row in rows:
    print(row.attrib['class'], row.text_content())
```

Result:

```
--- xpath ---

odd 
    Transferencias de Recursos do FUNDEB - Principal
    6.324.609,86

even 
    Cota-Parte do ICMS - Principal
    3.765.015,28

odd 
    Transferencias de Complementacao da Uniao ao FUNDEB - Princ.
    3.359.964,56


--- css ---

odd 
    Transferencias de Recursos do FUNDEB - Principal
    6.324.609,86

even 
    Cota-Parte do ICMS - Principal
    3.765.015,28

odd 
    Transferencias de Complementacao da Uniao ao FUNDEB - Princ.
    3.359.964,56
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version with `rvest` - it can use `'.odd, .even'` or `'//tr[@class="odd" or @class="even"]'`

```
library(rvest)

text = '
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="">Transferencias de Recursos do FUNDEB - Principal</td>
    <td align="right" class="">6.324.609,86</td>
</tr>

<tr class="even">
    <td class="">Cota-Parte do ICMS - Principal</td>
    <td align="right" class="">3.765.015,28</td>
</tr>

<tr class="advertisement">
    <td class="">Buy new cat</td>
    <td align="right" class="">3.359.964,56</td>
</tr>

<tr class="odd">
    <td class="">Transferencias de Complementacao da Uniao ao FUNDEB - Princ.</td>
    <td align="right" class="">3.359.964,56</td>
</tr>
'

html <- minimal_html(text)

message('--- css selector ---')

results <- html %>% html_elements('.odd, .even')

results

message('--- xpath ---')

results <- html %>% html_elements(xpath='//tr[@class="odd" or @class="even"]')

results
```

Result:

```
--- css selector ---
{xml_nodeset (3)}
[1] <tr class="odd">\n<td class="">Transferencias de Recursos do FUNDEB - Pri ...
[2] <tr class="even">\n<td class="">Cota-Parte do ICMS - Principal</td>\n     ...
[3] <tr class="odd">\n<td class="">Transferencias de Complementacao da Uniao  ...
--- xpath ---
{xml_nodeset (3)}
[1] <tr class="odd">\n<td class="">Transferencias de Recursos do FUNDEB - Pri ...
[2] <tr class="even">\n<td class="">Cota-Parte do ICMS - Principal</td>\n     ...
[3] <tr class="odd">\n<td class="">Transferencias de Complementacao da Uniao  ...
```